# RTAI on a debian distro - Unsure why this C thread code (implements a simple counter) would cause linux to crash

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, real-time

I have this code which implements a simple counter and writes it to a log file via printk in function void thread_code (void *arg), and then implements it in a real-time thread via __init rtcode_init(void). This question is an examination question.

I'm unsure why the code would cause linux to crash. Is it because of the static function, as that could cause a race condition if the memory address accessing the function was accessed by multiple threads? Would be great to have someone point out what is wrong with the code.

```
#define ARG 0
#define STACK_SIZE 1024
#define PRIORITY RT_SCHED_HIGHEST_PRIORITY
#define USE_FPU 1
#define NOW rt_get_time()
#define PERIOD nano2count(1000000)

/* Store data needed for the thread */
RT_TASK thread_data;

void thread_code(void *arg)
{
   int counter = 0;
   while (1) {
      counter += 1;
      printk("Counter = %d\n",counter);
   }
   return 0;
}

static int __init rtcode_init(void)
{
    rt_set_periodic_mode();
    start_rt_timer(PERIOD);
    rt_task_init(&thread_data, thread_code, ARG, STACK_SIZE, PRIORITY, USE_FPU, NULL);
    rt_task_make_periodic(&thread_data, NOW, PERIOD);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does the code also cause a crash if you use a lower priority?

Answer (score 1):

This code creates a task with realtime priority which runs constantly. If your system has only one CPU core, this will prevent anything else from running, making the system unusable. I don't think it'd "crash", precisely, but it'd stop responding to input.

Comment: That makes sense! So would adding rt_task_wait_period() to void thread_code(void *arg) then fix it? As the task would then be suspended until the next increment of the counter, where it would activate, increment and then be suspended again?

Comment: Possibly? Really, though, ideal would be to not use these RTLinux functions at all; they've been deprecated for years and years now. The standard nowadays is to use pthreads, not RT tasks.

Comment: Yeah, i realised the minute i steps into my labs. This is an outdated course but i'm taking it and i have to see it until the end. And that means using RT tasks, and whatever was given to me in the course lab sessions.